# Why is my truck cranking and not starting im get fuel pressure, and spark from the vehicle?

Tags: chevrolet, cranks-wont-run, s10

I have a 2002 chevrolet and s10 ls 4.3 and I changed thefuel pump and fuel filter and crankshaft position sensor  and I tried turn it over and I just get cranking and not starting

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How do you know you have spark and fuel pressure. I realize you've changed out the fuel pump and CPS, but did you observe spark and how did you check the fuel pressure? Is there fuel in the tank? Have you checked the fuses to the fuel injectors?